# Conditional formatting with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, jboss6.x

I'm trying to implement a file has Excel, conditional formatting. This is my code:

```
        XSSFSheetConditionalFormatting format = hojaReportePI.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
        /* Create a rule where different from 0 */
        XSSFConditionalFormattingRule rule = format.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.NOT_EQUAL, "0");

        /* Define the font formatting if the rule is met */
        /* The gray color for cells that do not comply with the format */
        XSSFFontFormatting rule_pattern = rule.createFontFormatting();
        rule_pattern.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLACK.index);

        /* Set yellow background fill for records that match */
        XSSFPatternFormatting fill_pattern = rule.createPatternFormatting();
        fill_pattern.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_YELLOW.index);

        /* Create a range of cells to which they apply formatting */
        CellRangeAddress[] data_range = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf(String.valueOf("J1") + ":" + String.valueOf("J") + String.valueOf(datosReportesPI.size()))};

        /* Attach rule to a range of cells */
        format.addConditionalFormatting(data_range, rule);
```

when executed I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() para servlet Faces Servlet lanz¾ excepci¾n:   
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl$1ConditionalFormattingList.
```

I am using jboss and apache poi; the library poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar and the entire library 3.11

please help thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the required jars are in the CLASSPATH ?

Comment: try to use the ooxml-schemas-xxx.jar instead of the poi-ooxml-schemas-xxx.jar

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI FAQ on this](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), and following the advice there?

Comment: You have to use the same version of jar files. It has to be 3.9 in your case.